# How to match first name first and if first name matched then last name in query DSL?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

I am indexing the names in Elasticsearch in one column, some name has only first name and others are first name and last name, I have used match_phrase, match_phrase_prefix, multi_match but it didn't give proper result, so any nested query can I used to match if the first name matched then only match the last name?

multi_match, match_phrase, match_phrase_prefix

I tried match_phrase, match_phrase_prefix query,

example1:

**input**: James.

**actual output:** Smith James, David James.

**expected output:** James Smith, James, James Thomas, etc.

Example2:

**input:** James Walker.

**output:** " Nothing"

**expected output:** James

Comment: You should create 2 fields in your elasticsearch, one for first name and one for last name. and then should use simple `match` query to search. this will be easy to maintain and your ES query will also be simple .. without this you might have  to create sime complex ES query

Comment: @AmitKhandelwal,  in my data many names contain only single words and if we pass the full name and it will return only last name that I don' want.

Comment: Sorry I didn't get you

Comment: Some name contains full name with more than 2 words and some with one word, in that case, what can I do? so indexing with two fields will not help.

Comment: can u explain above with some example ?

Comment: List of a name:[Bruce D. Porter, James Smith, Zsa Za Gabor, Thomas, Thomas James Smith Porter] in CSV. so here name contains 1 or 2 or 3 or more words,
In that case, how do I do indexing?

Answer (score 0):

If your purpose is to get list of names only. You can use completion suggester

Below is my Index

```
PUT my_index
{
    "mappings": {
        "properties" : {
            "name" : {
                "type" : "completion"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Query

```
POST my_index/_search?pretty
{
    "suggest": {
        "name-suggest" : {
            "prefix" : "<Search text>",
            "completion" : { 
                "field" : "name" 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Below is my full document

```
"hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "my_index",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "joqRxGoBW0RKSbIqHqsw",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "name" : "Smith James"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "my_index",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "j4qRxGoBW0RKSbIqP6uW",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "name" : "James Smith"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "my_index",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "kIqRxGoBW0RKSbIqUKvP",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "name" : "James"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

```
Query:
POST my_index/_search?pretty
{
    "suggest": {
        "name-suggest" : {
            "prefix" : "James",
            "completion" : { 
                "field" : "name" 
            }
        }
    }
}
]

Result:
"suggest" : {
    "name-suggest" : [
      {
        "text" : "James",
        "offset" : 0,
        "length" : 5,
        "options" : [
          {
            "text" : "James",
            "_index" : "my_index",
            "_type" : "_doc",
            "_id" : "kIqRxGoBW0RKSbIqUKvP",
            "_score" : 1.0,
            "_source" : {
              "name" : "James"
            }
          },
          {
            "text" : "James Smith",
            "_index" : "my_index",
            "_type" : "_doc",
            "_id" : "j4qRxGoBW0RKSbIqP6uW",
            "_score" : 1.0,
            "_source" : {
              "name" : "James Smith"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
```